# Invoking overloaded method from Delphi in DWScript

Tags: delphi, dwscript

In the `dwsDatabaseLibModule.pas` unit, which is included with the engine, the constructor of a class is invoked by accessing the class through TProgramInfo.Vars[]. Analogously, I was thinking I could invoke the overloaded method in the same way: `info.Vars['TMyClass'].Method['MethodName'].Call`.

Using the IInfo.Method property there, how do I distinguish between the overloaded methods?

Comment: Virtual has nothing to do with overloading. Do you mean overriding?

Comment: Sorry, a small hiccup in my explanation. I'll edit that. The problem is related to the overloading though.

Comment: There is currently no way to pick a particular overloaded method through IInfo, and I'm not sure how it could be done in a convenient fashion. You have to go down to the TClassSymbol.Members to identify the overload you want, and can then create TInfoFunc from that.

Comment: Could this be done without degrading the performance of the method? It would be convenient if there was a way to retrieve method info based on not only it's name, but also parameters. Or a way to retrieve all method infos with a specific method name, so the identification wouldn't degrade the performance too much.